# Flutter app background use of the compute function

Tags: android, http, dart, flutter

I'm learning Flutter and in my first app I try to use http to fetch a list of users. When I try to parse json response data using 'compute' function, my code broken. `"The function 'compute' ins't defined"`

[image: Error]

I have no idea what's happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import the foundation package. Put this in the beginning of the file

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
```

Comment: I can not believe I forgot that. Thanks.