# Can I use flutter compute function to http get?

Tags: flutter

I need to get responses from my API server with http.get or http.post in my flutter Application.

I need to do something similar to the question [Flutter app background use of the compute function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52336963/flutter-app-background-use-of-the-compute-function).

I wanna I can parse my response json in the compute function and this is ok, is it possible to compute() a function with inside the http.get request? 
This is because I see my spinner (CircularProgressIndicator) lagging while parsing data (resolved placing parsing function inside compute) and while performing requests over 3G/4G, maybe due to poor network performances.

```
print(await calculate("aaaaa"));


Future<String> calculate(String foo) async {
    var url = serverDomain+'/v1/search-event';
    var body = json.encode({
      "name": foo
    });
    // Lagging on await response??
    final response = await http.post(url, headers:globalHeader, body:body);
    return await compute(_isolate, response.body);
  }



//Very cpu intensive operation, no lag
static String _isolate(String a){
    var ab;
    print(jsonDecode(a));
    for (int i = 0; i < 999999; i++){
      ab = i ^ 2;
    }
    return a;
  }
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: see https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/background-parsing

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm doing, can I also compute() the get request?
When I deploy to mobile I see that probably awaiting for response the spinner lags

Comment: there is no need for it: [http](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/http) package uses async requests so you will never block the main UI thread

Comment: I think my code block here
`final response = await client.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos');`

Where my code wait for the response

Comment: no, it does not block the UI thread - it is only suspended - see [this](https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures) for more info

Comment: Yes, it's only suspended, but visually the spinner freezes.
Can you post an example of a function getting data from a fetch and print it to console?

Comment: i gave you a link in my previous comment

Comment: I edited my question so you can see my code, am I missing something?

Comment: `final response = await http.post(url, headers:globalHeader, body:body);` is fine - it does not block your UI

Comment: Ok, so what can block my UI? I've a spinner loading over when I execute my code, and during this the spinner block a little, probably due a network latency and then runs smooth, I tell network latency because if I run this over wifi, it's all fine and smooth

Comment: just for test add [CircularProgressIndicator](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/CircularProgressIndicator-class.html) in "Indeterminate" mode - do you see any hiccups?

Comment: Yes, I already had a CircularProgressIndicator in my app, previously called spinner.

Btw, I added another and Yes, I see hiccups before I can see the the response in the console then all goes smoothly

Comment: ok i see it now, by "spinner" i meant Android's `Spinner` - is it normal "debug" or "release" build?

Comment: debug but I builded now in release and it's still lagging :( 
Maybe less, not sure, but still a problem

Comment: Hi @PsyKoWebMari,  Did you find any solution? I'm also facing the issue.

Comment: `await http.post()` shouldn'

Answer (score 0):

`compute` can be used inside a Future with HTTP request and `http.post` shouldn't block the UI thread. How do you display the CircularProgressIndicator on screen? It will also be helpful if you're able to provide a repro for the endpoint used on your HTTP request. Since the endpoint wasn't provided I tried your minimal repro on Isolate with a mock HTTP request using Future.delayed to simulate its response time.

Here's how I display/hide the ProgressIndicator.

```dart
void _runCalculate() {
  /// show ProgressIndicator
  setState(() {
    showProgress = true;
  });

  calculate().then((value) {
    debugPrint('calculate finished: $value');

    /// Hide ProgressIndicator
    setState(() {
      showProgress = false;
    });
  });
}
```

I've modified your minimal repro a bit to mock a response delay from the HTTP request.

```dart
Future<bool> mockHttpRequest() async {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));
  return true;
}

Future<String> calculate() async {
  // var url = serverDomain+'/v1/search-event';
  // var body = json.encode({
  //   "name": foo
  // });
  // Lagging on await response??
  debugPrint('mockHttpRequest start');
  final response = await mockHttpRequest();
  debugPrint('mockHttpRequest end: $response');

  return await compute(_isolate, response);
}

//Very cpu intensive operation, no lag
static String _isolate(bool a) {
  int ab = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 999999; i++) {
    ab = i ^ 2;
  }
  return ab.toString();
}
```

[image: Demo]

Complete repro

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var showProgress = false;
  String? isolateResponse;
  void _runCalculate() {
    debugPrint('calculate start');
    /// show ProgressIndicator
    setState(() {
      showProgress = true;
    });

    calculate().then((value) {
      debugPrint('calculate finished: $value');

      /// Hide ProgressIndicator
      setState(() {
        showProgress = false;
        isolateResponse = value;
      });
    });
  }

  Future<bool> mockHttpRequest() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));
    return true;
  }

  Future<String> calculate() async {
    // var url = serverDomain+'/v1/search-event';
    // var body = json.encode({
    //   "name": foo
    // });
    // Lagging on await response??
    debugPrint('mockHttpRequest start');
    final response = await mockHttpRequest();
    debugPrint('mockHttpRequest end: $response');

    return await compute(_isolate, response);
  }

  //Very cpu intensive operation, no lag
  static String _isolate(bool a) {
    int ab = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 999999; i++) {
      ab = i ^ 2;
    }
    return ab.toString();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body:
              Center(
              child: showProgress
                  ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
                  : Text('Isolate response: $isolateResponse'),
            ),
          // }),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _runCalculate,
        tooltip: 'Run',
        child: const Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```